# Generate PDF button note working even after assigning HTML2PDF library

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas, html2pdf

I wrote the following code to make an HTML-based CV and added a button to generate a PDF of it. But whenever I click on the Generate PDF button, it just scrolls up the page. As you can see in the snippet, I've used the html2pdf library. But it isn't generating any results as expected.

```js
function generatePDF() {
      // Create a new jsPDF instance
      var doc = new jsPDF();

      // Get the CV container and convert it to a canvas element
      var cvContainer = document.querySelector('.container');
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = cvContainer.offsetWidth;
      canvas.height = cvContainer.offsetHeight;
      canvas.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';

      // Draw the CV content on the canvas
      html2canvas(cvContainer).then(function(canvas) {
        // Add the canvas content to the PDF
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 297); // A4 size: 210x297 mm

        // Save the PDF
        doc.save('Zia_ur_Rehman_CV.pdf');
      });
    }
```

```css
/* Custom CSS styles for the CV */
    body {
      font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.6;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      color: #333;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    h1, h2, h3 {
      color: #007bff;
    }
    p {
      margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    .section {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .contact {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .contact p {
      flex: 0 0 50%;
    }
    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #0056b3;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Zia ur Rehman</h1>
    <div class="contact">
      <p><strong>CNIC:</strong> 35202-0000000-0</p>
      <p><strong>Phone:</strong> 03240000000</p>
      <p><strong>Email:</strong> ziamobin@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Cutting Master</h2>
      <p><strong>Shahid Mehmood</strong></p>
      <p>Designers & Manufacturers of all Kinds of Uniforms & Garments</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Stitching and Cutting Master</h2>
      <p><strong>Haji M Jahanger</strong></p>
      <p>Men, Child Waistcoat Kurta Collection</p>
    </div>
        
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Cutting Master</h2>
      <p><strong>Zainerz</strong></p>
      <p>School & College Uniforms & Jackets</p>
      <p>Designers & Manufacturers Of All Kind Of Uniforms & Garments</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<!-- Add the Generate PDF button -->
<a href="#" class="btn" id="generate-pdf" onclick="generatePDF()">Generate PDF</a>

<!-- Include the html2pdf.js library from CDN -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Kindly highlight the errors in my code (if any) and suggest improvements. Thanks!

Comment: Console errors?

Answer (score 0):

It says jsPDF is not defined

Add this script tag in your html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```